# "Waiting for response" message when Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, response

When I use Ajax call(jquery) in the HEAD section I find a "waiting for response message" on a chrome browser with revolving circle. I don't want this ugly look. Is there a way to avoiding this?

---

PS: When I use input tag to call the JavaScript(Ajax call) function like

```
<input id="launcher" type="button" onfocus="go()" value="Go!"></input>
```

I couldn't see a waiting circle. Cause my program should call the function automatically I couldn't use this method.(If I use `document.getElementById("launcher").focus()` to automatically start the function, It showed waiting circle again.) I guess there's a some different context to call JavaScript function.

**Update** Here is my sample code

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function go() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myService",
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("result_area").innerHTML = data;
            go();
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    go() //Here I want to Comet call;
});
go(); //should start automatically.
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <!-- <input id="launcher" type="button" onfocus="go()" value="Go!"></input>
    This doesn't show the waiting circle. Why? Use different call context? -->        
<div id="result_area"></div>
</BODY>
```

Comment: When you call `$.ajax` in the head, are you wrapping it in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @nrabinowitz I'd lay 3:1 that this is the issue.  That should maybe be posted as a potential answer.  : )

Comment: Based on you showing a fragment of code that does work (as opposed to the code that actually causes you the problem) I would guess that you are doing a synchronous request, and that you get the delay when calling it from the head because it gets queued up with all the other HTTP requests that have to be made to generate the initial page. This is fairly wild speculation though as you haven't given us a reduced test case that could show us what is actually going on.

Comment: Why are you calling `go()` again from your success function? Are you trying to create an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes I use it to use an asynchronous request. I want to get notifications from server continually. If I put this code other than HEAD can it solve the problem? I think the code in BODY tags can't solve the situation. Where should I put this code? and then why it work in input tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this waiting circle on `XMLHttpRequest` is depend on a browser implementation. On IE7, Firefox4 it didn't show any waiting circle or bar while chrome11, Windows safari had one.

I believe that standard on this should be made cause it impacts greatly on user experience.

Comment: And Gmail on chrome has same problems. I guess gmail also used `XMLHttpRequest` call. Refer this.[link](http://www.google.ws/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6290d506bb282e30&hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

there are some issue i want to highlight

```
<input id="launcher" type="button" onfocus="go()" value="Go!"></input>
```

this should be

```
<input  type="button" id="launcher" value="Go!" />
```

then

- if u want a image instead of text then put a div before form  with **display:none**
- in *ajax* call you are not writing url link  with extension (**.php** or **.html** or **.js** )
- in success : you again calling `go()`, this smell like recursive function
- what data u r sending to the server?? **data:** is missing from ajax option
- also mention **dataType ( optional)**
- if you dont want to run ajax automatically then do it on some event( like i do on click)
- bind with the document ready
- write javascript code in head ( best practice to write just before `</body>`  )

i tried my hard to tell you the basic, here is my way

### HTML

```
<div id="waiting" style="display: none;">
    <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" title="Loader" alt="Loader" />
</div>
<form>
     // here is your form
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#waiting').show(500);
// instead run automatically now it will work on click of button
$('#launcher').click( function () {      
    $.ajax({
          url: "/myService.html", // or whatever page 
          // by the way where is data which you sent on server??
          data: { email : $('#email').val() }, // like i send the email to the serever
             dataType : "json",
             async : false,
          success: function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide();
            $("#result_area").html(data);
        }
    }); 
});
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But first, I don't need data in ajax call cause I don't have data to send. Second, I want to use Comet call to server so I need a recursive call here. Last, I should ajax call automatically. So if I use `document.getElementById("launcher").click()` I get the waiting circle again.

Comment: @user150497, that you did not mention in your question , thats why i suggest.

Comment: I think `document.getElementById("launcher").click()`, event sent from Javascript, and event from user are treated differently in a browser. Later case doesn't show waiting circle.(the "waiting response from.." message)